# Any issues with using "<namespace>.django.<app-name>" for django applications?

Tags: python, django

I know Django applications are typically named django-appname, however, our non-django packages are released under a namespace for our company (eg. company.modulename). Our Django applications are currently structured in a "django" namespace within that namespace (eg. company.django.appname).

We are evaluating our structure before releasing Django apps. Regardless of the internal path structure, which do you think would be a better project name convention for Django apps and why?

1. "django-company-appname" <-- more like community naming
2. "company.django.appname" <-- matches the internal structure and non-django python packages we release.

**Edit:**
Let me make this a little more clear. We already are using namespaces--our django apps are imported using "company.django.appname". What we are trying to decide, is if the name we use to release that app, as defined in setup.py and listed in PyPI/Github will be "company.django.appname" like our other Python releases or if we should do "django-company-app" instead.

Comment: Why is having "django" in the path so important?

Comment: As an example, we may have a regular python package for getting rates from the USPS web service called "company.usps" and we may also have a django application which adds USPS integration into a Django application called "company.django.usps". Helps us differentiate between similar packages between our standard Python code and Django apps.

Answer (score 0):

We use a company.modulename style namespace for a few django apps and have encountered no problems.

In the `__init__.py` files we declare the namespace.

```
import pkg_resources

pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
```

and it's worked fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing [absolute imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) will remove any chance of issues due to reuse of package names.